# Excel. Определение диапазона/матрицы для функции vlookup динамически

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть страница с данными в разных колонках. Исползуется Vlookup для поиска определенных значений по "ключу". Функция vlookup работает отлично, когда колонка ключа находится перед колонкой значений. Если это не так то нужно исползовать другую комбинацию функций Match и Index. Это очень громоздко в моем случае и тяжело для восприятия. Пользователи документа хотят и далее исползовать функцию vlookup. Может быть можно переопределеить динамически порядок колонок так, что бы ключ, находящийся на задних позициях переместился вперед, и подставить в параметр фунции уже эту для поска комфортную матрицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если надо... Это легче для восприятия?

```
=ВПР(B2;ВЫБОР({1;2};$B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7);2;)
```

Уж точно не быстрее в работе.

Comment: Не работает. Функция "ВЫБОР" указанна правильно?

Comment: Правильно. Для русской локали. В английской - `CHOOSE`. И лучше не голословно утверждать, а показывать в примере.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TORGecDwnC6tZe_O4k8qmSFM3hE9iC5I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: По сслыке выше excel-файл с примером, который не работает

Comment: Внимательнее надо быть... У Вас там три ошибки. 1) в массиве констант нужно указывать перечень столбцов, а не строк - {1;2} (разделитель не тот);  2) не закрепили ссылки на диапазоны; 3) поиск неточного соответствия (пропущен разделитель перед последней скобкой. `=ВПР(A1;ВЫБОР({1;2};$E$1:$E$10;$D$1:$D$10);2;)`

Comment: не работает, хоть ты меня убей. 1) так иделаю; 2) разделитель разный пробовал; 3) зачем крепить ссылки? хотя с крепежом тоже пробовал; 4) разделитель между последней скобкой не обязателен, хоть я и с ним пробовол

Comment: ===Если формула не копируется в другие ячекйки, закреплять диапазоны не обязательно. === Последний разделитель есть и после него нет числа - поиск точного соответствия (аналог варианта `;0)` ). Последнего разделителя нет - поиск неточного соответствия (аналог варианта `;1)` ). ===В комментарии выше рабочая формула для Вашего примераю Не работает? Где применяете - в `Excel` или похожих приложениях?

Comment: Да в Excel.....

Comment: Вы ни разу не показали СВОЮ формулу. Возможно, в Вашей версии Excel разделитель не точка с запятой, а запятая.

Comment: я работаю в нецком Excel , разделитель обычно - точка с запятой. Но я по разному пробовал: и с запятой тоже. А у вас работает? Если да, то поделитесь файлом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пришлите свой на почту

Comment: Выслал только что

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от vikttur оказался рабочим, но в немецкой версии Excel есть одна неочевидная особенность использования "choice". Разделителем в функции должна быть *точка*!

Вот рабочий пример:

```
=SVERWEIS(A1;WAHL({1.2};E:E;D:D);2; FALSCH)
```